# Comparing two timeStamps from different handsets

Tags: java, android

I am trying to compare the timeStamp values obtained from two different applications using the System.currenttimeMillis(). I am running these applications during the same time interval in two different smart-phones that are built by the same company and have the same service operator connection.

My confusion is that when I am comparing these timeStamped values from the two different apps but using the same procedure for generating timestamped values i.e. System.currenttimeMillis(), these values are varying a lot. And I am not able to justify the reason for this, can someone throw some light onto it.

And another query I would like to ask that if I want to compare the two timeStamp values from two different apps, what is the best function I should employ for comparing the values. Note: the accuracy is paramount (approximately in milliseconds)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp for different devices can change because of the differences between the CPUs. Moreover, you may use a DELTA which is relatively small to understand whether it is different or not.
Assume that what you get from the first device is TIMESTAMP1 and the other is TIMESTAPM2. So, if TIMESTAMP1-TIMESTAMP2>DELTA then they are different, otherwise they are same.

Comment: can you clarify me, what do you exactly imply by DELTA. If you do have some relevant links can you post it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it is normal that the timestamps are not identical. you could try to use a local NTP server to lower the delay for the time sync between your devices. or maybe GPS time. but i am not sure if the device can "process" the gps time that fast that the time is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I am implementing the two apps on handsets which are constrained to be within the buildings so I don't have an access to GPS. And Stefan I don't want to lower the delays but I do want to grab the exact timeStamp values during certain time interval using two different handsets.